# Taking 2d list, and writing program for column max and average

Tags: python

i have a hw assignment i just finished up but it looks pretty horrendous knowing that theres a much simpler and efficient way to get the correct output but i just cant seem to figure it out.
Heres the objective of the assignment.
Write a program that stores the following values in a 2D list (these will be hardcoded):

```
2.42 11.42 13.86 72.32
56.59 88.52 4.33 87.70
73.72 50.50 7.97 84.47
```

The program should determine the maximum and average of each column

Output looks like

```
 2.42 11.42 13.86 72.32
56.59 88.52 4.33 87.70
73.72 50.50 7.97 84.47
============================
73.72 88.52 13.86 87.70 column max
44.24 50.15 8.72 81.50 column average
```

The printing of the 2d list was done below, my problem is calculating the max, and averages.

```
data = [ [  2.42, 11.42, 13.86, 72.32],
         [ 56.59, 88.52, 4.33,  87.70],
         [ 73.72, 50.50, 7.97,  84.47] ]
emptylist = []
r = 0
while r < 3:
    c = 0
    while c < 4 :
        print "%5.2f" % data[r][c] ,
        c = c + 1
    r = r + 1
    print
print "=" * 25
```

This prints the top half but the code i wrote to calculate the max and average is bad. for max i basically comapred all indexes in columns to each other with if, elif, statements and for the average i added the each column indency together and averaged, then printed. IS there anyway to calculate the bottom stuff with some sort of loop. Maybe something like the following

```
for numbers in data:
    r = 0       #row index
    c = 0       #column index
    emptylist= []         
    while c < 4 :
        while r < 3 :
            sum = data[r][c]
            totalsum = totalsum + sum
            avg = totalsum / float(rows)
            emptylist.append(avg)        #not sure if this would work? here im just trying to
            r = r + 1                    #dump averages into an emptylist to print the values
    c = c + 1                            #in it later?
```

or something like that where im not manually adding each index number to each column and row. The max one i have no clue how to do in a loop . also NO LIST METHODS can be used. only append and len() can be used. Any help?

Comment: what do you consider as "list methods"? `max` is also included?

Comment: In your `for numbers in data` loop, `numbers` will sequentially take on the three rows in `data`, but you never use it.  Effectly, since there are three rows in `data`, you're just repeating the code in that loop three times, identically each time.

Comment: As shown, your `c = c + 1` line is not within your `while c < 4` loop.  Thus, `c` will remain zero and that while loop will keep on going infinitely.

Comment: @Zach, please consider selecting or upvoting one of the answers below if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making a two new lists, each of the same size of each of your rows, and keeping a running sum in one, and a running max in the second one:

```
maxes = [0] * 4 # equivalent to [0, 0, 0, 0]
avgs  = [0] * 4
for row in data:      # this gives one row at a time
    for c in range(4):   # equivalent to for c in [0,1,2,3]:
        #first, check if the max is big enough:
        if row[c] > maxes[c]:
            maxes[c] = row[c]
        # next, add that value to the sum:
        avgs[c] += row[c]/4.
```

You can print them like so:

```
for m in maxes:
    print "%5.2f" % m,
for s in sums:
    print "%5.2f" % s,
```

If you are allowed to use the enumerate function, this can be done a little more nicely:

```
for i, val in enumerate(row):
    print i, val
0 2.42
1 11.42
2 13.86
3 72.32
```

So it gives us the values and the index, so we can use it like this:

```
maxes = [0] * 4
sums  = [0] * 4
for row in data:
    for c, val in enumerate(row):
        #first, check if the max is big enough:
        if val > maxes[c]:
            maxes[c] = val
        # next, add that value to the sum:
        sums[c] += val
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you're looking for:

```
num_rows = len(data)
num_cols = len(data[0])
max_values = [0]*num_cols # Assuming the numbers in the array are all positive
avg_values = [0]*num_cols
for row_data in data:
    for col_idx, col_data in enumerate(row):
        max_values[col_idx] = max(max_values[col_idx],col_data) # Max of two values
        avg_values[col_idx] += col_data
for i in range(num_cols):
    avg_values[i] /= num_rows
```

Then the `max_values` will contain the maximum for each column, while `avg_values` will contain the average for each column. Then you can print it like usual:

```
for num in max_values:
    print num,
print
for num in avg_values:
    print num
```

or simply (if allowed):

```
print ' '.join(max_values)
print ' '.join(avg_values)
```